# Java Encryption/Decryption

Tags: java, encryption

Help me I cant get the decryption to work?
This program already get the Encryption but not the decryption how can I fix this?

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class CIBAw
{    
    public static void main(String[] argv)  
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner File = new Scanner(System.in); 
        try
        {
            KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
            SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
            Cipher desCipher;
            desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
            System.out.println("Encrypt a File");
            System.out.print("Enter a sentence:"); 
            //String file = File.nextLine(); 
            byte[] text = "".getBytes();
            System.out.println("" + new String(text));
            // Encrypt the text
            byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
            System.out.println("File Encryted : " + textEncrypted);
            // Initialize the same cipher for decryption
            desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
            // Decrypt the text
            byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(textEncrypted);
            System.out.println("File Decryted : " +  new String(textDecrypted));

        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NoSuchPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(InvalidKeyException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(BadPaddingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do, and what does it actually do? (Knowing those two things is the universal first step to debugging a problem)

Comment: This program encrypts an empty string and then decrypts it again. And what on earth does JSON have to do with it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok after looking at this, I changed the code around to make it more readable and to give you a better technique into how to approach this problem:

1. Read the input.
2. Create an instance of the Keys (public/private).
3. Cast the input into a byte.
4. Encrypt the input and print it out.
5. Decrypt the input and print it out.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       try
       {

           //Prompt for String
           System.out.print("Enter a sentence:");
           String in = input.next();

           //Generate Key for encryption/decryption
           KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
           SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
           Cipher desCipher;
           desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
           desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

           //Cast the input into bytes 
           byte[] text = in.getBytes();
           System.out.println("" + new String(text));
           // Encrypt the text
           byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
           System.out.println("File Encryted : " + textEncrypted);
           // Initialize the same cipher for decryption
           desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
           // Decrypt the text
           byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(textEncrypted);
           System.out.println("File Decryted : " +  new String(textDecrypted));

       }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch(NoSuchPaddingException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch(InvalidKeyException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch(BadPaddingException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 

   }
   ```